# How to get rid of large classes with numbers from views?

Tags: views, theming

Which is the purpose of classes like that one:

```
class="js-view-dom-id-0fc70eec09ba01f6b7c7867ee7e19f7dcec1ee8b64de9dc8b791865caf299ec7"
```

It's safe to change this class from twig templates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used to uniquely target views elements with javascript for AJAX purposes. If you have enabled the use of AJAX on your views display for pagination, filtering etc without page reloads, then removing or changing those might break it. If you are not using AJAX at all, you should be fine, although this comment is not a promise or guarantee!